# android intent-filter <data> is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, android-activity, intentfilter

I am trying to have my application intercept on a specific URL in browser. following is my code in the Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.myactivity.RootActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="subdomian.maindomain.com" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

it is working fine at the moment, when I open the link http://subdomain.maindomain.com/ , a dialog comes up with my activity listed on it.

but when I add `android:path` in the intent-filter like below, it stops working, it doesn't even work with simple url without the path.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.myactivity.RootActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="subdomian.maindomain.com" />
                <data android:path="myPath" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I tested what you said using these links and its working for me

```
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:host="developer.android.com" />
<data android:path="/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html"/>
```

And the intent i used is

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

The `android:path` must match after the host url that you gave for it to work ?
Can you specify what URL did you use ?
Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path) link for help